# Typescript :- create generic type for function taking object having one key as type of value and return type is value

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I am struggling to type the function. below snippet throwing error in this line `export type DataAttributeType<T> = BACKEND_PRIMITIVE[T]`;

I want to create a function that takes the example input and returns the example output.

Example 1:

```
input:- {"S": "2015-02-18T20:27:36.165Z"}
Output:- "2015-02-18T20:27:36.165Z"
```

Example 2:

```
input:- {"N": 10 }
Output:- 10
```

What I have tried:

```
export const enum DATATYPE {
    S = "S",
    N = "N"
}

type BACKEND_PRIMITIVE = {
    [DATATYPE.S]: string;
    [DATATYPE.N]: number;
};

export type BackendDataAttributeType<T> = {
    [T in DATATYPE]?: BACKEND_PRIMITIVE[T];
};

export type DataAttributeType<T> = BACKEND_PRIMITIVE[T];

export const mapToPlainObject = <T>(
    attribute: BackendDataAttributeType<T>
): DataAttributeType<T> => {
    if (attribute.S) {
        return attribute.S;
    }
    if (attribute.N) {
        return attribute.N;
    }

    throw new Error("Not able to parse attribute");
};
```

The problem is I am not able to preserve the return type the same as the input. If the key is S then the return type should be a string.

Help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You should define your allowed base types. Then define your wrapper attribute class. Then define a function that returns the base type from the wrapper class.

### Example of Wrapping and Attribute

```
    // The limited set of types for attributes
    type AlllowedAttributeType = string | number | { foo: string, bar: string};

    // Create a rich interface for you data type
    interface MyDataAttributeType<AlllowedAttributeType> {
      name: string;
      data: AlllowedAttributeType;
    }

    // Type of the function that returns the attribute value
    type GetAttributeValue = 
      (input: MyDataAttributeType<AlllowedAttributeType>) => AlllowedAttributeType;

    // Return just the value part
    const myGetTypedData: GetAttributeValue = (input) => {
      return input.data;
    };
```

#### Usage

```
    const d1 = {
      name: 'data1',
      data: 1,
    }

    const d2 = {
      name: 'dataTwo',
      data: 'Two',
    }

    const d3 = {
      name: 'complex',
      data: { foo: 'biz', bar: 'baz' }
    }

    console.log(myGetTypedData(d1));
    console.log(myGetTypedData(d2));
    console.log(myGetTypedData(d3));

    const d4 = {
      name: 'error',
      data: { wrong: 'type' },
    }
    // wont compile
    console.log(myGetTypedData(d4));
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure what you're trying to do, but my instinct here is to write `mapToPlainObject` like this:

```
const mapToPlainObject = <T extends Partial<BACKEND_PRIMITIVE>>(
    attribute: T
): T[keyof T] => {
    return attribute[(Object.keys(attribute) as Array<keyof T>)[0]];
};
```

Here I'm saying that you will pass in something that has some of the properties of `BACKEND_PRIMITIVE` (I guess it will always be exactly one such property) and it returns one of them (and if there's exactly one then it returns that one).  (Note that `Object.keys()` returns `string[]` in TypeScript, but I'm asserting that it will be an array of the known keys of the `attribute` type.  This isn't technically safe, but I'm assuming your input will not have extra unexpected keys in it.

This gives the input/output relationship you're mentioning and the compiler is aware of the output type:

```
const str = mapToPlainObject({ "S": "2015-02-18T20:27:36.165Z" });
// const str: string;
console.log(str); // "2015-02-18T20:27:36.165Z"
const num = mapToPlainObject({ "N": 10 });
// const num: number;
console.log(num); // 10
```

You might have other use cases that necessitate a more complicated type signature; if so, please add them to the question so they can be addressed.  Otherwise, hope that helps; good luck!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/MYewdgzgLgBApmArgWxgEQIIBVsE0AKAojAN4CwAUDNTAMowC8MARLcwDSU0wByjLPZpQC+lSlACeABzgwAQhgDCAaUI80AfXwAlAJIBZXVl0A1Yk3JUaAbUw4sBQgDpaAXQBcMaACcAlmABzAG4uGzs8IiceDxgkZAAjOG8QimEUylBIWGQAQyksEHwAGxz-AHl4gCs4YFgmAB4seAAPKAQAEwgYfBzvKF8covqFFTVNHQMjU0IAPhmAClDqHKgoP3jENs8sSgBKbesAazgJEAAzGCxXRhnSJZhvOChEbzAYFbXfDbbreYrq2pOY4SCDzD7rTZwXbvLoYbzeHISerA86XGa7awABlcrhSaTEFEy0C8a34uXyhRK5SqNSg8xILDYnmYACZMQBGACsAFpMSzueyABxYNnuFkAdncAGYAGxOdkyzkALWYMGEuxSAHpNTAibAfJ4fP5ghlwBAQEU4E4iiAAvMfBqYNqWGyubz+UKRZixZLZfLFSrTVlYigyXkCsVSmB-rT6QJmJ52Zi1RrKM69SHkJ44olkkHzZbrbb5nFHc6k0A)

Comment: I am getting JSON like { [type]: value } where the type(key) has some predefined values and it represents the data type of value and yes it would be a single key. It is a attribute type of dynamodb where each attribute like { [type]: value }.

Comment: If the code in this answer doesn't work for you, let me know; preferably with some examples showing why.  Good luck again!